# Jenkins HTMLPublisher Plugin not displaying on the dashboard

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, redhat

After moving my jenkins home directory from `/var/lib/jenkins` to `/home/jenkins` for more disk space with the following commands:

```
sudo service jenkins stop
sudo mv /var/lib/jenkins /home
sudo ln -s /home/jenkins /var/lib/jenkins
sudo service jenkins start
```

the HTMLPublisher plugin is no longer displaying the link on the left panel of the dashboard.

Following is what the console outputs

[image]

Following is what I have in the post build part of the Jenkins pipeline:

```
        publishHTML([
            allowMissing: true,
            alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
            keepAll: true,
            reportDir: 'builder',
            reportFiles: 'lighthouse-report.html',
            reportName: 'Lighthouse Report',
            reportTitles: ''
        ])
```

Note: this was working prior to changing the home directory for more disk space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permanent solution (which survives a restart) was simply to delete lighthouse-report.html from the src location. Then refresh the page and you're able to see it at the updated path.